# Accessing parameters of custom action filter attributes into IsAuthorized

Tags: filter, authorize-attribute, actionfilterattribute, webapi2

I have created custom attribute for Web api 2. I inherited from Authorize attribute. New attribute takes params attribute like
**public MyAuthorizeAttribute(params string[] scopes){}**

and usage will be something like this 
**MyAuthorizeAttribute("Test1","Test2")**.
How can i access Test1 and Test2 into 
**protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext){}**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

BaseClass constructor call was not made. So default constructor was getting called.